# Convert NativeScript application to Web application

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

Is it possible to convert NativeScript Application (Angular 5 typescript) to mobile app. By googling, I found [NativeScripting](https://nativescripting.com/course/nativescript-with-angular-web-application-conversion/) and [nativescript-ng2-magic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ng2-magic) but that was not much useful. My question is how to convert nativescript to web code? There's not a single example available on internet to do so.Can someone suggest how to achieve this?